# Divs don't merge

Tags: html, css

I have this layout:

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to make the `div` with a slideshow, this above the red thing, be above the section of header.

I tried `z-index`, and a lot of other ways, but cannot get the layout to work.

This is my code:`

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="imagens/1.png" alt="Curso 1" class="banner" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="imagens/2.png" alt="Curso 2" class="banner" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="imagens/3.png" alt="Curso 3" class="banner" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="imagens/4.png" alt="Curso 4" class="banner" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="imagens/logo.png" id="" /></a>
        </div><!--logo-->
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <a class=""><li>HOME</li></a>
                <a class=""><li>PROGRAMAÇÃO</li></a>
                <a class=""><li>PALESTRANTES</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--header-->
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
#box {
    width:980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:red;
}
#header {
    z-index: 3;
}
#slideshow {
    height:286px;
    width:980px;
    z-index: 0;
    float: right;
}
#slideshow ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#slideshow img {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:286px;
    width:980px;
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

I'm trying to do something like this: [image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm unclear what you want it to look like. Also, you might consider getting a working example up in jsfiddle.net -- easier for others to adjust/help/test.

Comment: I'm just guessing what you want here, but try `position: absolute;` on  the images?

Comment: @gregmac so, i had updated what i need to do, with an image...i thing its can help u to see, but with this example had u answer, cant get this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by "merge" you mean overlap.

To make the logo and navigation (`#header`) overlap the slideshow (`#slideshow`) above it, you will need to put a negative top margin on `#header`. You also need to add position to an element in order for z-index to work.

```
#header {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top:-200px;
}
```

Once you do this, you may need to increase the `z-index` property of `#header` in order for it to get to overlap your slideshow.

Comment: so, i had updated what i need to do, with an image...i thing its can help u to see, but with this example had u answer, cant get this effect.

Comment: Please give me a link to a live example so I can take a look at it for you.